# AutoMapper MapExpression for sub-entity fails

Tags: c#, automapper-9

I'm mapping select expression (projection) of Linq query. This is done to decouple logic layer from data access layer and logic layer should use only DTOs.

```
Expression<Func<CountyInfoDto, CountyInfoDto>> selector = c =>
new CountyInfoDto
{
    Id = c.Id,
    Citizens = c.Citizens.Select(p => new CitizenDto
    {
    }).ToList()
};

var resEx = mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<CountyInfo, CountyInfoDto>>>(selector);
```

This mapping fails with error `Expression of type 'DTOs.CitizenDto' cannot be used for return type 'Entities.Citizen'` however in `CountyInfoDto` property `Citizens` has type `CitizenDto`. Please note all mapping profiles are valid and simple objects can be mapped properly.
If I do like this, all works:

```
Expression<Func<CountyInfoDto, CountyInfoDto>> selector = c =>
new CountyInfoDto
{
    Id = c.Id
};

var resEx = mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<CountyInfo, CountyInfoDto>>>(selector);
```

or this also works:

```
Expression<Func<CountyInfoDto, CountyInfoDto>> selector = c =>
new CountyInfoDto
{
    Id = c.Id,
    Citizens = new List<CitizenDto>
    {
        new CitizenDto
        {
            Id = c.Citizens.First().Id
        }
    }
};

var resEx = mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<CountyInfo, CountyInfoDto>>>(selector);
```

is there any possibility to avoid this error?

Classes:

```
public class CountyInfo
{
    public CountyInfo()
    {
        Citizens = new HashSet<Citizen>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Citizen> Citizens { get; set; }
}

public class Citizen
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}

public class CountyInfoDto
{
    public CountyInfoDto()
    {
        Citizens = new List<CitizenDto>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<CitizenDto> Citizens { get; set; }
}

public class CitizenDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
CreateMap<CountyInfo, CountyInfoDto>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<Citizen, CitizenDto>().ReverseMap();
```

I'm using `AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping`, after update to latest version error is: `No coercion operator is defined between types 'Entities.CountyInfo' and 'DTOs.CountyInfoDto'.`

Comment: Can you please add code for you classes and mapper configuration?

Comment: @GuruStron I've added new info, please take a look.

Comment: BTW have you tried just `db.Counties.UseAsDataSource().For<CountyInfoDto>().Select(selector)`? Or it fails with the same exception?

Comment: @GuruStron if I understand correctly after `For<CountyInfoDto>` I will be able to access only properties specified in `CountyInfoDto`, but in general I need to filter by any property in my Entity and select any another set of properties

Comment: You can apply your filtering before `UseAsDataSource()` as far as I understand.

Comment: @GuruStron ok, but also as I understand if I do `For<CountyInfoDto>` that is going to include all navigation properties which are mapped there. But technically I need to expand only particular properties in this query and another set of navigation properties should be expanded in another query. To solve this issue I will have to create so many different DTOs for `For` projection however I want only to modify query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214321/discussion-between-guru-stron-and-alexey).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214394/discussion-between-alexey-klipilin-and-guru-stron).